# Does changing window.location stop execution of javascript?

Tags: javascript

When writing server-side code you need to explicitly stop execution after sending a "Location: ..." header to the client or your code will continue to execute in the background.

But what about when you change window.location in a client-side script? Does this immediately stop execution of the current script or is it up to the programmer to make sure that any code located after this call is not reached?

Comment: @DavidAndersson What else would your +1 imply?

Comment: @stolsvik almost anything, including it is useful, shows research effort, and is clear. Maybe it is also just worth reading, funny, intriguing, etc?

Comment: I had to explicitly call `return;` on the next line to get out of the flow and let window.location do its thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Setting `window.location` does not implicitly stop JS execution. Take the following as an example:

```
function locationTest() {
  window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
  window.open('http://www.yahoo.com/');
}

locationTest();
```

Try running that from Firebug/Web Inspector/etc. and you'll notice that the current window will load Google, but a new window will open with Yahoo as well.

Comment: This could be a race condition. I can imagine that old scripts stop executing when the new location has completed loading

Comment: On Safari it seems that it stop execution after window.location

Answer (score 22):

> Does this immediately stop execution of the current script

No, the remaining handler script will execute to the end before control returns to the browser and events start happening. When loading of the new page gets far enough for ‘navigation’ to occur, the `beforeunload` and `unload` events will fire, *then* the page and any script in it will become inactive.

However, any further queued events and timeouts might not fire. For example if you navigate the page in a `click` handler of a form submit button and don't cancel the default action, it is possible (race condition) for the navigation to occur before the `submit` event queued by the default action of the `click`.

Comment: Thanks. As a corollary to this question, is there any way to detect when you're in this state (i.e., `window.location` has changed but navigation has not yet occurred)?

Comment: Thanks, just the answer I needed. Is your answer based on observing how browsers work, or is this behavior defined somewhere?

Comment: The answer was based on observation, but some work has been done in HTML5 on standardising browser control flow—asee eg https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-loops,  https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#navigate. The standards we have ended up with are largely unreadable, and still leave a bunch of stuff unspecified, but we're still in a better situation than the inconsistent and mysterious one we had before.