# Javascript blocking on post request

Tags: javascript, post, filepicker.io

I have, what I believe to be a pretty normal and sane javascript function, below:

```
$scope.pickFile = function() {
    filepicker.setKey("...");
    filepicker.pick(
        {},
        function(Blob) {  // OnSuccess
            var uuid = Blob.url.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
            window.location.replace("/url" + uuid);
            $.post(
                "/other_url" + uuid,
                {'input': $('#rawText')[0].checked? "text" : "features"}
            );
    });
}
```

Now, the bizarre thing is that the redirect doesn't happen until the post request finishes. My gut says this might be some magic happening behind the scenes with filepicker, but I have no idea what it might be, and there doesn't seem to be any documentation around it.

It doesn't seem to be simple synchronicity either since the redirect is actually first, but it is blocking on the post request completing.

Comment: at a cursory glance the `post` might need occur prior to the  redirect with the `window.location` perhaps? (Or the redirect in the callback?)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Apologies, I'm not quite following. It has to happen after the POST request is sent, but not after the response, which is what's happening.

Comment: I guess another way to rephrase is are you looking for something like `window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  do post here;
};`

Comment: This is the context of where my thought are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536793/does-changing-window-location-stop-execution-of-javascript

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I think that's unrelated to my problem. It's waiting for the post request to complete, which is what I want to stop. It does this even if I remove the redirect altogether.

Comment: Ok so if you do `$.post(
                "/other_url" + uuid,
                {'input': $('#rawText')[0].checked? "text" : "features"}
            ); return false;` does that address your  issue (the return false?)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Unfortunately not. No change. I thought it was fixed for a second, but it just erred early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the post to explicitly not include the callback handler:

```
var mypost = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:  "/other_url" + uuid,
  data:  {'input': $('#rawText')[0].checked? "text" : "features"}
});
return false;
```