# JavaScript getElementsByTagName is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-rendering

when i am loading a web page using the code `window.location` . I want to get the text inside the paragraph. when i using the below code i didn't get the answer. How to get the contents of web page when using window.location. The page loading is working successfully. But the content is not getting proper.

```
$(function(){
    window.location="http://xxxxxxxxx/";
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        console.log(x[0]);


    }
```

The output is showing  `undefined`. I didn't get the correct answer. Is it possible please help me.

Comment: Your title says `getelementbyid` but your code uses `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: You're trying to get the `p` for which page? The original or the newly loaded one?

Comment: Try using `document.querySelector`

Comment: You are navigating away from the page, of course the script after `window.location` won't run.

Comment: window.location is navigating away and your title is not the same as your content, please fix it. and you will never get a log from this code because of window.location. also even if you are sending it to the same file it will be infinite requests and the browser will discard it...

Comment: Your code is working. `window.location` navigates to the new page, however, your `document` is still referencing the page before it moved. And yes, your next line after still executes it's just not looking at the page you think it is looking at.

Comment: If your technique worked this would’ve been a serious security issue.

Comment: @KrisztiánDudás @RolandStarke The code in the old page doesn't stop executing but instead code within the current block should complete, with exceptions, such as `setTimeout` and similar. DOM queries and `console.log()` should continue executing. This SO explains it better ► https://stackoverflow.com/a/2536954/448144 - Either way, in the case of OP `document` refers to the current page and will only find elements on that but will not refer to the new page.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `window.location="http://xxxxxxxxx/";` you will navigate to your new page. In this page you don't have your javascript, therefore you don't try to access it.

You can't execute some javascript from a previous page in the next.