# Should I use `never` type for function which call `location.replace`?

Tags: typescript, navigateurl, typescript-never

I have a piece of TypeScript code like this

```
function askLogin(): never {
    location.replace('/login');
}
```

However, typescript report an error:

```
A function returning 'never' cannot have a reachable end point.
```

Should I change to `void` return type here? Or what the best I can do here?

Comment: Why should it return `never`? JS execution will *continue* after `location.replace()`, at least some amount.  You can see that [here](https://tsplay.dev/W4aYBw), if you look at your console logs, you'll see evidence of execution after `location.replace()`. The right return type is `void`. If you really want `never` you should probably `throw` something yourself. Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?

Comment: add `throw new Error("Can't replace url")` after `location.replace`

Comment: _"I have a piece of TypeScript code"_... did you write it and if so, why?

Comment: @jcalz Didn't know that the function may continue execute after replace. So maybe that's another question about how to stop the execute. But your comment answered the question that I should simply use `void` here.

Comment: @Phil I post a question because there is a bug in my code. Everyone want some debugging helps on this site typically write some code which does not work somehow, i believe.

Comment: I just meant is this your code or somebody else's. And if it's yours, did you have a reason for using `never` as the return type

Comment: @Phil As I thought that location.replace never returns (which is incorrect as suggested by previous comment), so this function will returns never.

Comment: Ah right, I understand where you're coming from now. You can always check the DOM typedef for clarity ~ https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.location.html#replace

Answer (score 1):

Although changing the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) has the effect of navigating, possibly away from the current page, it doesn't necessarily immediately stop execution of JavaScript. You can test for yourself that, in at least some browsers, some amount of JavaScript will still be run afterward. See [Does changing window.location stop execution of javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2536793/2887218).

So [the TS library call signature for `location.replace`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L14645) returns [`void`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void) and not [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#never).  And similarly, your `askLogin()` function should return `void` and not `never`, since it is quite likely that your function will return normally. For example, in my browser (Firefox) I see `"HELLO"` in the console logs for the following code:

```
function askLogin(): void {
  location.replace('/login');
}
askLogin();
console.log("HELLO");
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.2#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgIYGcDWAZBBzOCACgEpkBvYZZAGwSlXiQDoAnAUwAcbUp2iA5HQIQBJANzAAvsAw58hUpKhJ0CGu2bCiAIgASAUWzYA8jonIgA)

If you want `askLogin()` to return `never`, you'll need to make sure the function does not return normally yourself, say by [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)ing an exception:

```
function askLogin(): never {
  location.replace('login');
  throw new Error("Replaced URL, Goodbye cruel world");
}
askLogin();
console.log("HELLO"); // error, unreachable code
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.2#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgIYGcDWAZBBzOCACgEoAuZCAUwDcqAnZAb2GWQBsEpV4kA6elQAO7VFCpEA5JwIRJJANytkMABb0EAd0pVtAUXob6RAEQAlYaPEATZAFUz2ADTIA4ggTWARgE8qyKHowKnZkTQR6dmsTRWAAX2AMHHxCUiUoJHQEdio+GVMACT1sbAB5GIVkAHoq5AYjF0hBMVVULxyAzyogA)

That doesn't necessarily stop all execution everywhere, since some outer scope might [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) your exception and do stuff. But there's no good way to avoid that, really. (You *could* try to make your function loop forever instead of throwing, but that has a good chance of preventing the location replace from occurring at all, depending on the browser.)

Comment: Thank you for your detail explain. I just misunderstood the behavior about `location.replace`. Finally, I had returned a `new Promise<never>(() => {})` instead, and add await in the caller. (luckly, the caller first await some backend api to get current user profile, and call askLogin if the first ajax failed, so it is already async).